Receive and confirm the waiting list to join the group or channel
I have a Telegram bot that sends an invitation link to the user. This link is created with the ability to request admin approval, and the user must apply for membership.
My main question is that this program is made with telethon, when I want to confirm or reject requests to join a group or channel, I cannot find the method and code related to this operation.
What command can be used in this library to confirm join requests?
I used most of the methods but I did not get any useful results
